# WooCommerce action hook to redirect to new page on order failed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to redirect to a custom wordpress page if a customers woocommerce order fails.

I have found and implemented the following code which redirects to a new page upon payment success.

Is it possible to add to this code, so a failed order is sent to another specific url ?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom');

function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have, you can use `$order->has_status( 'failed' )`

So you get:

```or-tag-here
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Settings
        $url1 = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url-1';
        $url2 = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url-2';

        // Compare
        if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url1 );
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url2 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

---

Code goes in `functions.php` file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works in Wordpress 5.8.1 & WooCommerce 5.8.0